# How to find the multiple values are present in arrays with same decimals

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here I have array to find the multiple values are present for same decimal keys in `QNoMarks` array

```
var QNoMarks = [{"1.1":"4%"},
                {"1.2":"3%"},
                {"1.3":""},
                {"2":"2%"},
                {"3":"8%"},
                {"4.1":"5%"},
                {"4.2":""},
                {"5":"6%"},
                {"6.1":"2%"},
                {"6.2":"1%"}
               ];
```

How to Find the multiple values are present in same decimal values. In QNoMarks

eg output below

```
{"1.1":"4%"},{"1.2":"3%"},{"1.3":""} // multiple value found in 1.1 and 1.2
{"2":"2%"} // no multiple value
{"3":"8%"} // no multiple value
{"4.1":"5%"},{"4.2":""}, // no multiple value
{"5":"6%"}, // no mulitple value
{"6.1":"2%"},{"6.2":""},{"6.3":"1%"} // multiple value found in 6.1 and 6.3
```

Comment: It is called bucket sort. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort

Comment: The input array appears to be sorted already and the output differs very little from the input. I. e. there are linebreaks instead of commas in some places. Is this really all you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

you can do so in the following way

```js
var QNoMarks = [{"1.1":"4%"},
                {"1.2":"3%"},
                {"1.3":""},
                {"2":"2%"},
                {"3":"8%"},
                {"4.1":"5%"},
                {"4.2":""},
                {"5":"6%"},
                {"6.1":"2%"},
                {"6.2":"1%"}
               ];
let result = {};               
for(let element of QNoMarks){
    for(let property in element){
        let prefix = property.match(/(\d+)\.?/)[1];
        result[prefix] = result[prefix] || [];
        result[prefix].push(element);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

here I have grouped all objects which have the same number before the decimal point. I am using regex to get the value

Answer (score 0):

You could group by the integer value of the key and use a hash table for same groups.

```js
var data = [{ "1.1": "4%" }, { "1.2": "3%" }, { "1.3": "" }, { "2": "2%" }, { "3": "8%" }, { "4.1": "5%" }, { "4.2": "" }, { "5": "6%" }, { "6.1": "2%" }, { "6.2": "1%" }],
    groups = Object.create(null),
    result = [];
    
data.forEach(function (o) {
    var key = Math.floor(Object.keys(o)[0]);
    if (!groups[key]) {
        groups[key] = [];
        result.push(groups[key]);
    }
    groups[key].push(o);
});

console.log(groups); // as object with group keys
console.log(result); // as array
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Group them by the integer using reduce:

```js
let QNoMarks = [{"1.1":"4%"},{"1.2":"3%"},{"1.3":""},{"2":"2%"}, {"3":"8%"}, {"4.1":"5%"}, {"4.2":""}, {"5":"6%"}, {"6.1":"2%"}, {"6.2":"1%"}];
let res = QNoMarks.reduce((a, b) => {
  let key = Math.floor(Object.keys(b)[0]);
  a[key] = (a[key] || []).concat(b);
  return a;
}, Object.create(null));
console.log(res);
```